# WPF Application not installing

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, oracle11g

I am currently trying to install a WPF application I have created for my team.  I developed this app with Visual Studio 2010, and is connected to an Oracle DB version 11.2.0.3.0.  I have a Windows XP machine and I am trying to install it in Windows 7 machines.  I have successfully installed this app on two Windows 7 machines, but the other machines get an error saying:

Problem Event Name: CLR20r3

There are Problem signatures shown, and one of them shows Oracle.DataAccess

The machines that are having problem installing this app also has Oracle 11.2.0.3.0.  Do they also need to somehow upgrade their ODAC? Or is that part of that version?  I am also not sure if they have the .Net 4 Framework.  If they do not have that, could that be a possible problem?

Comment: Do a Google search for CLR20r3 - interesting and perhaps useful

Comment: I have already done this and it's not giving me an answer that helps me with my problem.